# Setting "allow_pickle=True" by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am encountering the error message

> ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False

while running a tool designed by somebody else (see [DUDes](https://github.com/pirovc/dudes)). The solutions proposed in [the related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55824625/6151828) suggest setting `allow_pickle=True` directly in the `np.load` function. (My understanding is that the code in question was created while this used to be the default behavior of `np.load`, which has changes since then.) I would like to resolved this issue without tinkering with the original code. The obvious solution would be reverting to the earlier version of `numpy`. However, I am wondering whether, it is possible to simply change the default behavior for `np.load` in the (whatever) current version of numpy/python?

Comment: you could monkey-patch it if you want

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could you give more details? This sounds cryptic to me...

Comment: `import numpy as np` then `np.load = <my version of load>`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but this should be done in the original code, which I do not want to modify?

Comment: No, this is done in the code *you are writing*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the code in question is launched from the command line. I do launch it from a python script though, via `sp.call` - is this what you mean?

Comment: I do not know what `sp.call` is. It really isn't clear to me what you mean.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok, Suppose I simply run it from the command line. Could you provide instructions on how to monkey-patch the existing code?

Comment: You can't really do much from the command line. It's going to require at least a little python code.

Comment: @mousetail it is okay tow rite some python code, but I need a more specific prescription of what this code is, where it is placed and when it is run. I have looked up a bit about [monkey-patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching), and in this context it seems to suggest recoding the np.load function.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that has worked for me so far is [downgrading `numpy` to a version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57609893/6151828) with default setting `allow_pickle=True`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python=3.7 numpy=1.16.2
```

[*Monkey-patching*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5626193/6151828) was suggested as a possible solution in the comments, but it is still not clear (to me) how to implement it here.